# Convert string representation of coordinate from given CRS using geo tools

Tags: java, geometry, geography, geotools

I have a string representation of a point in a given CRS (namely, `EPSG:3035`), such as "`N10160E21266`". I'd like to **parse it** using *GeoTools* to create a `DirectPosition`, or any another X/Y representation *(in order to transform it from a CRS to another CRS; I have a MathTransform at hand)*.

**Is there a parse method already implemented somewhere in GeoTools?**

It's probably not difficult to create a custom one, but this may be error-prone and I'm not a GIS specialist (how to properly handle north/easting etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not a well known representation so there will be no standard parser. It shouldn't be too hard to write one that returns a DirectPosition or a JTS.Point.

The only geographic issue that you need to bear in mind is that [epsg:3035](http://spatialreference.org/ref/epsg/etrs89-etrs-laea/html/) stores east as X and north as Y (which in this case is what you'd expect). You'll need to check the axis order of your target projection.